# Custom search results usign Search API + views

Tags: 7, search

I am currently using Search API for indexing my content . I use Views for displaying search results and Views exposed filter for search form. In the search results page I use facets to filter based on content type, created date etc. I need to upgrade the search feature and provide the following features. Please let me know the Modules or APIs that can help me achieve this.

1) Split the search results based on content type. 
Ex: If there are any nodes of content type A, content type B in the search results, I need to display the top 2 nodes of the content type A , top 3 nodes of content type B and the rest of the results.
Formatting of the result display is based on the content type.

2)In the facets I would like to display custom group names instead of the actual content types.
 Ex: If there are multiple content types like 'Books', 'Articles', 'Magazines' etc I would like to display the link in Facets as a single entry 'Publications' and in the view filter based on the actual content types.

Is it possible to achieve the above 2 features using search API? I am open to changing the approach for displaying search results(alternative for Views and exposed filter if required).

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

1) Although I can't give you the exact answer, what you're looking for is probably View Attachments (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9GC-trMH0o). That allows you to display part of the view in a different way.

2) No idea.

Comment: Thanks. Will try out View attachments with Facets to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For 2) it seems like you can use the module [Search API combined fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_combined)